# way to have query with case statement

Tags: sql, case

I have table called Numbers in that column I have values from 0 - 10  but I like to keep value of 1-10  only change record of 0 too null

**Case numbers
when 0
then ''**

but I found this has changed all values and not values that have 0 is there way I can say else leave value as is?

Comment: What are you using by the way, `sql server`, `mysql`, etc..? are you doing an `update` or a `select`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
update t
    set number = null
    where number = 0;
```

Or as a `select`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when number <> 0 then number end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [column] = 0 THEN NULL ELSE [column] END AS [SomeName]
FROM Numbers
```